# How do I limit the amount of times a JMS DefaultMessageListenerContainer will retry a message?

Tags: java, jms, ibm-mq

I am using Spring JMS to connect to a Websphere MQ server. I implemented the SessionAwareListener interface to create a custom listener, reusing old code for the business logic.

While testing, the listener throws a StringIndexOutOfBoundsException, which I fail to catch. However, I see in the log the following printed about 32 times, then the DMLC stops.

```
WARN  - Execution of JMS message listener failed
```

Is there a way to control how often the DMLC will retry a message, and how to handle uncaught exceptions?

Comment: So u r using the IBM MQ JCA adapter right? Where is your Spring application deployed?

Comment: No we are only using Websphere MQ, not the application server. The Spring application is a standalone JVM.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can always check the JMSDeliveryCount. If it is more than the number you consider as maximum then just don't process the message and return.

You can also [configure your Websphere](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/techarticles/0803_titheridge/0803_titheridge.html) to move the bad message to the exception destination after some attempts.

Comment: Thanks for the article. That helped to see what was happening on the backend. I'm now using the JMSXDeliveryCount and JMSRedelivered JMS properties to handle the message.

Comment: Do you happen to know anything in the Spring API that could also help in error handling?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know much about Spring my friend.

Comment: Lol no worries. I'm trying to figure it out myself. But using Spring has removed a lot of boiler-plate code. All I had to do was define the MessageListener. Worth learning IMO.

Comment: I've always used plain JEE and I am quite happy with it

Answer (score 5):

Putting back a message to the queue after some error is called *backout* in the Websphere MQ world.

There are two alternatives how to handle it:

1. In the queue manager: You can configure *backout threshold* and *backout requeue name* properties for the given queue. After backout treshold is reached, queue manager will put the message to the queue specified by the backout requeue name instead of redelivering it. See [WebSphere MQ queue properties](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.mq.explorer.doc/e_properties_queues.htm&resultof=%22BOQNAME%22%20%22boqnam%22) for more information.
2. In your application: If you use JMS API, check the JMSXDeliveryCount property by calling [msessage.getIntProperty("JMSXDeliveryCount")](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.3/api/javax/jms/Message.html#getIntProperty%28java.lang.String%29) before you start processing the message. If it reaches some treshold, handle the message as errorneous.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Yours in conjuntion with DaTroop helped in solving the problem.

Comment: On 1, the MQ properties are BOTHRESH for the retry limit, and BOQNAME for the queue where the message will be forwarded once that retry limit is reached.